# Call selectable function on collide

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, editor

I remember unity having the ability to call a function of your choosing on colliding with another object or something like that from the editor. How do I do this? Or am I just imagining this?

Comment: Please modify and clarify your question. It's hard to tell what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `UnityEvent`:

```
public UnityEvent myEvent;


void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    //do your collsiion logic here

    myEvent.Invoke();
}
```

This gives you something like this in the inspector. Assign a game object and choose the public function that should be called.

[image]